# Linux Mint Вход в систему через флешку с отпечатком

Tags: linux, linux-mint, auth

Имеется Linux Mint 20.3 с Cinnamon 5.2.7 и флешка с подключаемым разделом по отпечатку пальца. Возможно ли описать свой аутентификатор, чтобы входить в систему по отпечатку с флешки? Что почитать по этому поводу?

Comment: Я бы начинал с [`pam_usb`](https://github.com/mcdope/pam_usb). Этот модуль аутентифицирует по набору < *вендор*, *модель*, *серийный номер устройства*, *uuid раздела* >. Если у вашего секретного раздела есть UUID, модуль `pam_usb` должен его найти.

Comment: прошу тебя оформить коментарий в виде ответа. так как pam_usb решает мою проблему в полном объеме. подключаемый раздел флешки имеет другой UUID, по которому модуль способен найти раздел и произвести аутентификацию. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы начинал с [pam_usb](https://github.com/mcdope/pam_usb). Этот модуль аутентифицирует по набору < *вендор, модель, серийный номер устройства, uuid раздела* >. Если у вашего секретного раздела есть UUID, модуль `pam_usb` должен его найти.